# Making android app compatible with Kitkat and above versions

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-4.4-kitkat, android-5.1.1-lollipop

I am new to android . I want to have an app does gives backward compatibility also means it should support versions from kitkat and above. If I make Project build target(Properties --> Android) to Android 5.0 (API-21) then it means it will run in lollipop only? If I want to add support library then which library should I import right now I have seen people importing appcompat v7 library for lollipop development. I know this one is quite basic question.

Comment: You use Android Studio or Eclipse??

Comment: Edit your old answer. Don't ask a new one. Deleting your old badly received question and reasking it will only hurt your credibility on this site and could eventually lead to an automatic ban if your average question quality is too low.

Comment: @akhilbatlawala Eclipse :) Don't tell me studio is better.I knw that alreday but still want to use eclipse

Comment: @akhilbatlawala using Android Studio or Eclipse makes exactly what difference? This user has asked this question before, don't answer it...

Comment: @XaverKapeller Dude what's your problem.I did not find suitable answer there and my question was wrong (not clear) so instead of editing ,I by mistake deleted it.What's the big deal. Grow up kiddo..!!!

Comment: @Loren nothing, but deleting your badly received question and reasking it is explicitly forbidden on Stack Overflow and as I explained continued behavior like this will eventually lead to an automatic question ban. I am just warning you. It is always better to edit your old question.

Comment: @Loren and what do you mean you did not find a suitable answer there? You waited maybe not even two hours? I was about to post an explicit answer but you just delete your question. You know you can undelete the question as well, do you? Getting good answers on Stack Overflow can take days and I am just trying to warn you that this behavior is not in your own best interest.

Comment: @XaverKapellerYou can post that answer here. I am new to Stack overflow .Don't know much about it's strict rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write Minimum sdk version in your manifest file

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="19"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
```

Just set minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion  in app gradle file.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "guard.proguard"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

}
```

Comment: This answer is wrong. The manifest file does not control settings like that anymore.

Answer (score -2):

You control the compatibility in the manifest file.

```
    <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="15"
    android:targetSdkVersion="22" />
```

Comment: This answer is wrong. The manifest file does not control settings like that anymore.